# Kendo Grid (ASP.NET MVC) Error with Unicode Character

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a problem with a Kendo grid that is filled with a DataTable. It worked fine, until I added some unicode characters to the column names of the DataTable that is passed to the grid. An invalid template error is thrown and I'm pretty sure it's because of the unicode character.

```
Error: Invalid template:
    '<tr data-uid="#=data.uid#" role='row'>
       <td  role='gridcell'>#:data.CID==null?'':data.CID#</td>
       <td role='gridcell'>#:data.INFO==null?'':data.INFO#</td>
       <td  role='gridcell'>#:data.HISTORY==null?'':data.HISTORY#</td>
     </tr>'
Generated code:
    'var $kendoOutput, $kendoHtmlEncode = kendo.htmlEncode;with(data)
    {$kendoOutput=
        '<tr data-uid="'+(data.uid)+'" role=\'row\'>
           <td  role=\'gridcell\'>'+$kendoHtmlEncode(data.CID==null?'':data.CID)+'</td>
           <td  role=\'gridcell\'>'+$kendoHtmlEncode(data.INFO==null?'':data.INFO)+'</td>
           <td  role=\'gridcell\'>'+$kendoHtmlEncode(data.HISTORY==null?'':data.HISTORY)+'</td>
         </tr>'
    ;}return $kendoOutput;
```

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the encoded value as false. 
If set to true the column value will be HTML-encoded before it is displayed

```
 columns: [
    { field: "name", encoded: false }
  ]
```

Example :

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "sample", encoded: false }
  ],
  dataSource: [ { sample: "<strong>Sample String</strong>" } ]
});
```

If the issue is related kendo in  .net core then check [this](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/invalid-template-error-when-using-localization)

Comment: I tried it with adjusted `GridColumnSettings`. The `encoded=false` setting runied the rows of the grid and didn't fix the error. 
I will change the columnnames with JavaScript, as this seems to be the easiest workaround right now.
Anyway, thanks for your help!